# php - mySQL select date week for year

Tags: leap-year

I have 1 column contains the date format

date:
2013-09-22
2013-09-23
2013-09-24
2013-09-25
2013-09-26
2013-09-27
2013-09-28
2013-09-29
2013-09-30
2013-10-01
2013-10-02

Today is the 40th week of the year. I want to select all days have 40 weeks to do the like. Looking forward to your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mysql function date_format.

```
select * from tableOne where date_format(myField,'%U')=40;
```

See [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: If it solves your problem, mark the answer as correct, so other users don't waste time reviewing already answered questions ;)